# path=logout - how to configure URL it redirects to?

Tags: members, global-variables

I have put a logout link on my site. When I click it, I am logged out and redirected to the homepage. How do I specify a different page to redirect to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always recommend my add-on Authenticate.

https://objectivehtml.com/authenticate/documentation/tag/logout-url

```
{exp:authenticate:logout_url return="/some/return/url"}
```

Comment: I've encountered some problems using Authenticate: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/2194/objectivehtmls-authenticate-login-and-forgot-password-problems

Answer (score 3):

I use a add-on for member management on the front-end called FreeMember. This add-on offers a more fine grained control for member management using regular templates. (including return url after logout).

https://github.com/expressodev/freemember

Answer (score 2):

Another option, besides [FreeMember](https://github.com/expressodev/freemember) is [LogIn Redirect](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/login-redirect). Generally speaking, the standard login/logout doesn't offer you much leeway in modifying redirects, but either of these plugins (and others) aim to improve that experience.

Answer (score 0):

The User add-on by EE Harbor has a nice little Logout form, which allows you to create a return path.