# ObjectiveHTML's Authenticate - login and forgot password problems

Tags: add-on, authenticate

I'm trying to use https://objectivehtml.com/authenticate and have come across some problems:

**Logon Form:**

1. How can I trigger a global error so I can verify `{global_errors}` work? See: https://objectivehtml.com/authenticate/documentation/tag/global-form-variables
2. How do I access a specific field error? `{field_errors}` does display the first error encountered in the form, but I can't seem to access a specific field error. I've tried `{error:email}` doesn't work for me.

**Forgot Password:**

1. How do I specify the form's class and return URL? See: https://objectivehtml.com/authenticate/documentation/tag/forgot-password

**Both Forms:**

1. How do I persist the form inputs when there is an error and the page is displayed again? I want the email and password to be persisted on form errors.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will look into each of these issues and get back with you. I am still working on a number of updates for Safecracker Reg which you also requested, so I will likely just do it all at the same time.

Comment: Thanks Justin. I'm guessing that some of my "problems" are just due to me being new to EE, etc. Looking forward to your updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Login Form

1. Global Errors are triggered after the form has been validation. So if all your required fields have values, and adhere to all the custom validation rules, it will pass the validation. So if your username and password is incorrect, that is a global variable and not assigned to any particular fields. Rather, it applies to all the fields. The core library behind all this is called Base_form.php and it is used for a lot of different things. So Global Errors in Authenticate are different than another add-on.
2. This was a bug that fixed in the latest version (1.2.7). You could have used the `{field_error:your_field_name}` but that was not working correctly either. So I fixed all this and made a `{error:your_field}` variable in the process to make things easier.

#### Forgot Password

The `class` attribute is global. There are bunch of undocumented parameters actually. I will try to document these next chance I get.

```
{exp:authenticate:forgot_password return="/some/url/path" class="your-class"}
```

#### Both Forms

You can use the `post:` prefix, like so:

```
 <input type="text" name="email" value="{if post:email}{post:email}{/if}" id="email">
```

*The public repo for Authenticate has been updated. If you are having problems with Safecracker Registration and want the latest version, contact support[at]objectivehtml.com*

Comment: can you please verify that `post:email`, etc. works? I'm trying to persist user entry when the form has errors. It seems like when the form has errors and is submitted, the user is redirected to the same page. Are POST values still available after a redirect?

Comment: Yes, because the form should be posting back to itself, or at least back to another page with an Authenticate login tag. I can definitely confirm it works, I tried it yesterday specifically and can confirm other people use it too.